# Inserting text content using same class multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm currently trying to insert text content that change depending of image validation using a single class for multiple divs. Any help is appreciate!

**HTML**

```
...
<div id="trophies"><img id="trophyimage" src="//user/trophies/A.png" height="100" width="100">
<span id="text-content" class="spaner"></span></div>
<div id="trophies"><img id="trophyimage" src="//user/trophies/B.png" height="100" width="100">
<span id="text-content" class="spaner"></span></div>
<div id="trophies"><img id="trophyimage" src="//user/trophies/C.png" height="100" width="100">
<span id="text-content" class="spaner"></span></div>
```

Right now using the next Javascript it's inserting the text content but it only does it once per ".spanner" class, not in the rest.

**JavaScript**

```
 var trophy = document.getElementById("trophyimage");
 if(trophy.src == "...//user/trophies/A.png"){
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("spaner")[0]; 
   x.textContent = "Trophy A";
 }
 else if (trophy.src == "...//user/trophies/B.png"){
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("spaner")[0];
   x.textContent = "Trophy B";
 }
 else{ var x = document.getElementsByClassName("spaner");
   x.textContent = "Null";
 }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it work using something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
var trophiestext = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("spaner"));
trophiestext.forEach(function(troph) {
  var trophy = document.getElementById("trophyimage");
  if(trophy.src == "...//user/trophies/A.png"){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("spaner"); 
    x.textContent = "Trophy A";
  }
  else if (trophy.src == "...//user/trophies/B.png"){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("spaner");
    x.textContent = "Trophy B";
  }
  else{ var x = document.getElementsByClassName("spaner");
    x.textContent = "Null";
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using triple equals inside the if statements. Double equals is basically useless in Javascript. `if (src === 'some/path') `

Comment: Use same name for the id is not recommend, id is unique identifier. You can rename the id to trophyimage1, trophyimage2, trophyimage3, and use querySelectorAll("spaner")), check the related id, if it's trophyimage1, display "Trophy A"

Comment: Duplicate id in HTML is invalid and will behave in odd ways or not at all. Fix that first. 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: You keep re-defining =`x` with this `var x =` which is going to cause challenges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there is a problem, multiple HTML elements cannot share the same id attribute, you must switch them for classes, also "//user/trophies/A.png" is probably not a valid directory

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="trophies">
    <img class="trophyimage" src="../user/trophies/A.png" height="100" width="100">
    <span class="text-content spanner"></span>
</div>
<div class="trophies">
    <img class="trophyimage" src="../user/trophies/B.png" height="100" width="100">
    <span class="text-content spanner"></span>
</div>
<div class="trophies">
    <img class="trophyimage" src="../user/trophies/C.png" height="100" width="100">
    <span class="text-content spanner"></span>
</div>
```

Now, JavaScript can handle your HTML much better

**Javascript:**

```js
// Don't forget the dot before the word trophies
const trophies = document.querySelectorAll('.trophies')

trophies.forEach(element => {
    const img = element.querySelector('.trophyimage')
    const src = img.getAttribute('src')
    const span = element.querySelector('.spanner')

    // change for the src to fit your files
    if (src === '../user/trophies/A.png') span.innerText = 'Trophy A'
    else if (src === '../user/trophies/B.png') span.innerText = 'Trophy B'
    else span.innerText = 'Null' // Actually writes the word null, for no text use empty quotes
})
```

If you need more help, just reply to this answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use classes, add descriptions based on that and then add a generic description to those not found.

```js
let trophyDesc = [{
  name: "type-a",
  description: "Trophy A"
}, {
  name: "type-b",
  description: "Trophy B"
}, {
  name: "type-c",
  description: "Trophy C"
}, {
  name: "type-unknown",
  description: "Trophy Grand"
}];
const result = trophyDesc.find(({
  name
}) => name === 'type-unknown');
//console.log(result.description);
let trophies = document.getElementById("trophies");
let trophylist = trophies.getElementsByClassName("trophy");
//console.log(trophylist);
for (var i = 0, len = trophylist.length | 0; i < len; i = i + 1 | 0) {
  let t = trophylist[i];
  for (let d of trophyDesc) {
    let hasClass = t.classList.contains(d.name);
    if (hasClass) {
      let e = t.querySelector(".trophy-text-content");
      e.textContent = d.description;
      t.classList.add('found');
      break;
    }
  }
}
// now do not found ones
const f = trophies.querySelectorAll(`.trophy:not(.found)`);
for (let n of f) {
  n.querySelector(`.trophy-text-content`).textContent = result.description;
}
console.log(f.length);
```

```css
.trophyimage {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="trophies">
  <div class="trophy type-a"><img class="trophyimage" src="//user/trophies/A.png" alt="a">
    <span class="trophy-text-content">A</span></div>
  <div class="trophy type-b"><img id="trophyimage" src="//user/trophies/B.png" alt="b">
    <span class="trophy-text-content">B</span></div>
  <div class="trophy type-c"><img id="trophyimage" src="//user/trophies/C.png" alt="c">
    <span class="trophy-text-content">C</span></div>
  <div class="trophy type-u"><img id="trophyimage" src="//user/trophies/u.png" alt="u">
    <span class="trophy-text-content">U</span></div>
</div>
```